# Parse Local Data Store as a Replacement for Core Data (iOS) and SQLite (Android)

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, core-data, parse-platform

I am in the process of developing several apps on iOS and Android for which I would like implement a single-user multi-device sync. Parse Local Datastore for iOS and Android seem to be interesting options for storing data locally because they have a built in mechanism to sync data to a backend using `saveEventually`.

My question is, to what extent can Parse Local Datastore be considered a replacement for Core Data (iOS) or SQLite (Android) for local storage? My apps would probably store several hundred objects each.

Comment: Better to post this question on http://parse.com

Comment: Did you found your answer?

Comment: Parse is shutting down so it doesn't matter much now.

Comment: What should we do ? @ChemDev  I have started to create a new app for a month. When I heard this new, my morale is down. :( I dont wanna look other services.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is a viable replacement for Core Data on iOS (I cannot speak towards Android).  In my usage I have found it to be more of a "temporary cache" rather than a true persistence engine.  Since there is no way to tell it what to keep, how long to keep it, etc. it should be considered a cache at best.